# Google API Error on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services, google-maps-android-api-2

I getting a few issues with the Google Play Service Libraries.

I have imported these files:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
```

I am getting errors throughout the project for "GoogleApiClient":-

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

Here I get errors with locationClient/ LocationServices/ GoogleApiClient

```
locationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
              .addApi(LocationServices.API)
```

Here is get errors for "locationClient"

```
 @Override
  public void onStop() {
    // If the client is connected
    if (locationClient.isConnected()) {
      stopPeriodicUpdates();
    }

    // After disconnect() is called, the client is considered "dead".
    locationClient.disconnect();

    super.onStop();
  }

  /*
   * Called when the Activity is restarted, even before it becomes visible.
   */
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // Connect to the location services client
    locationClient.connect();
  }
```

Here I get error for "onConnectionSuspended"

```
  @Override
  public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
       Log.i(Application.APPTAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
  }
```

Comment: Remember: got an error? Add a full logcat

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have included Google Play Services in your build.gradle dependencies, for example:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have all permissions in the manifest and sha1 code.

Comment: @MohamedSalad Yep, need that too, but not having those set up would not cause compile errors, it would cause runtime errors.